# Magento product->getUrlPath() returning empty

Tags: product-urls

I'm debugging a customers environment, so don't have all the details at place, sorry about that.

My problem is that apparently the call to product->getUrlPath() returns empty.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Yes, thank you. The spelling error was in the question, not in code.

Comment: It's OK.. Where you are trying this code?

Comment: In a class derived from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit
$this->getProduct()->getUrlPath();

Answer (score 4):

There could be a lot of causes.

1. your db is inconsistent and there is not `url_path` for your product. (most probably this is not it)
2. Your intexes are not up to date
3. You are calling `$product->getUrlPath()` from a product collection and the `url_path` attribute is not added to the collection.
   The correct way to add them is like this:

   ```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToselect('...')//attributes that you need, * for all attributes
      ->addUrlRewrite();//this will join with the url rewrites table
   ```

But I don't think of a case where you need the `url_path`. I didn't need it before.
In case you need the product full url, you can call `$product->getProductUrl()` and you will have it. Again...if you call this while iterating through a collection make sure you have `addUrlRewrite()` to the collection.

Comment: I'm not calling from a collection.  Indexes are up to date.